# Ms access form became transparent

Tags: windows, forms, ms-access-2010, transparent

i designed an ms access app on ms access 2010 , the operating system is windows 10.
Now when i run the app on window 7 ,, the navigation form and its content is working well , but the pop up forms become transparent and you can see the data in navigation form behind through the pop up form, also labels of pop up form's is hidden .
by the way back style of the form is normal .

Pleas help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: please just tell me if my question is not clear .

Comment: please help about this issue , i got tired .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after changing adding and deleting  so many thing , i found the solution which was unexpected.
its just to change (personalize) your windows 7 theme to (windows 7 basic) theme